# Developing an universal android application (phone and tablet) - Defining Orientations

Tags: android

I have developed an android application, which only supports portrait orientation, for android phones. Now, I need to modify this app because I want to do the universal version (for tablets, too) but I have a problem. The phone version only supports portrait orientation and the tablet version supports portrait and landscape orientations. Is there any way to define different orientations for tablets and phones?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can create a subfolder in the res/layout folder, called xlarge-land and xlarge-port with the xml files in them. the device itself will know what xml to load.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

resource: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of supporting landscape mode only on a tablet.