# Different orientations for android phones and tablets

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android app, I want the screen orientation to be portrait for phones and support both portrait and landscape for tablets. I researched about the similar questions on stackoverflow but they dont really solve the problem. I want to know is it practically possible to make orientation changes by adding the screenOrientation tag in manifest or if I make changes for phone, it is reflected for tablets as well? The link I found most close to my issue was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872135/developing-an-universal-android-application-phone-and-tablet-defining-orient)

Comment: Hi Rashmi, did you found any solution to this. Is it possible to handle it on the manifest file itself.

Answer (score 0):

u can create in resource floder as this..

res/layout-port/my_layout.xml ----- for mobiles

res/layout-xlarge-port/my_layout.xml -----for tablets
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml -----for tablets

u need to declare the orientation in manifest for every activity as android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation